# tkinter freezes due to after() method

Tags: python, tkinter

The problem is the .after() method inside the 'get_content' function. The delay freezes the whole program. I tried solving it with threading but I can't figure it out. I tried a lot of variations. I will just post the code with the last one! Any suggestions? (The code still needs some fixes here and there but the freezing issue is really annoying and I want to get rid of this first)

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from sentences import sentences
import threading
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Speed typing test")
root.geometry('700x700')

# Dynamic labels
entry_text = tk.StringVar()
seconds = tk.IntVar()

# Stopwatch
def seconds_counter(*args):
    if not entry_text.get():
        seconds.set(0)
    else:
        counter = 0
        while counter < 100:
            counter += 1
            root.update()
            root.after(1000)
            seconds.set(counter)
            global total_time
            total_time = counter
            if entry_text.get() == sentence:
                final = (len(entry.get()) / 5) / (0.1 * total_time)
                final_lbl = tk.Label(root, text=f"WPM: {final}")
                final_lbl.pack()
                entry.delete(0, tk.END)
                seconds.set(0)
                word_list = sentence.split(' ')
                total_words = len(word_list)
                total_words_lbl = tk.Label(root, text=f'Total words: {total_words}')
                total_words_lbl.pack()
                counter = 0
                break

x = threading.Thread(target=seconds_counter)
x.start()

sentence = random.choice(sentences)
sentence = sentence.strip('.')
# Create widgets
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('images/logo.png'))
logo_lbl = tk.Label(image=logo)
sentence_lbl = tk.Label(root, text=sentence)
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=500, textvariable=entry_text)
seconds_lbl = tk.Label(root, textvariable=seconds)

# Place widgets
logo_lbl.pack()
sentence_lbl.pack()
entry.pack()
seconds_lbl.pack()

entry_text.trace('w', seconds_counter)

def stop():
    root.destroy()

# command=quit freezes for some reason
btn_quit = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=stop)
btn_quit.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What did you intend to achieve by calling `after`? My suggestion would be that you delete it, so it won't freeze your program.

Comment: It freezes for one second to make the timer work. If I delete it it will jump to 100 in a fraction of a second

Comment: The one-parameter version of `.after()` is basically useless - it's exactly equivalent to `time.sleep()`, and will simply lock up your GUI for the specified duration.  The normal usage, with two or more parameters, schedules a function to be executed in the future - in the meantime, the GUI remains fully interactive.

Comment: You can't loop like that in a GUI.  When you change a UI element like that, nothing happens immediately.  What that does is send a message.  The message won't be fetched and dispatched until your handler returns and Tk gets back to the main loop.  Only then will drawing be done.  You need to do one update, then call `root.after(1000)` to get a callback, and return.  When it calls you again, you can make your next updates.

Comment: I think I will completely change it. Just had a thought.. assign a start var and finish var with time.time thus not even needing the while loop